# Warm starting a pyomo model with a feasible point but it is converging to be local infeasible with IPOPT solver

Tags: python, pyomo, nonlinear-optimization, ipopt

I am working in pyomo, ipopt and python.

1. I have a black box model that I believe gives correct solutions to my optimization problem. I tried warm-starting it with these solutions like so:

> ```
> model.re_pwr_gen = Var(gen_list, within=Reals) #p^g_i
> for gen in gen_list:
>         model.re_pwr_gen[gen].set_value(warm_data['re_pwr_gen'][gen])
> ```

To which I get the resulting:

> ```
> EXIT: Converged to a point of local infeasibility. Problem may be infeasible.
> WARNING: Loading a SolverResults object with a warning status into
> ```

2. To investigate this further I tried fixing the variables instead to look for infeasibilities:

> ```
> model.re_pwr_gen = Var(gen_list, within=Reals) #p^g_i
> for gen in gen_list:
>      model.re_pwr_gen[gen].fix(warm_data['re_pwr_gen'][gen])
> #check if variable is infeasible with relevant constraints
> for g in gen_list:
>         if model.gen_re_upper_constr[g]() > gen_dict[g]['p_max']:
>             infeasible_constraints["gen_re_upper_constr"].append(g)
>             print(str(model.gen_re_upper_constr[g]) + " " +str(model.gen_re_upper_constr[g]() - gen_dict[g]['p_max']))
> ```

And I found that sometimes the constraints are broken by very small amounts, for example:

> ```
> gen_re_upper_constr['10'] over by: 1.9404932771749372e-08
> ```

3. Finally I tried adding these tolerances to my constraints:

> ```
> def gen_re_upper(model, g):
>     return model.re_pwr_gen[g] <= gen_dict[g]['p_max'] + tol
> model.gen_re_upper_constr = Constraint(gen_list, rule=gen_re_upper)
> ```

And I still get local instabilities! Does anyone have a better idea on how ipopt and pyomo handles warm start values to help me understand what's going on here?
Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes, the option `bound_relax_factor` can help. Of course, active-set methods are better when doing restarts.